# Rename file for Nexus

Tags: maven, deployment, nexus

Background: we are migrating an application and have to adopt some new structures so the autmatic installation process works at our customers site.

Until now we are using maven-classifiers to build 3 different flavours of the same module (say flavours A, B and C). The problem is the automatic installation process at our customers site can't handle this as we expect. While downloading from the nexus, the 3 artifacts overwrite each other and only the last is actually there.

There is absolutely no way, that we can fix this issue from the customer side (although it would be trivial!). Actually, our customer won't change absolutely anything on his site - we have no control whatsover of the enviornment on our customers site.

So the proposed solution to make this work, to deploy 3 artifacts with different artifactIds. I.e. modA, modB and modC

My question is: **how to achieve this in the 'most elegant way'?**

We don't want to restructure the whole project as truly triplicating the number of modules would be horrendous.

My ideas so far of which I'm not even sure if they would work:

- Use antrun plugin to copy/rename files and generate the corresponding pom files from a template and then use deploy-file to upload to the nexus.
- Using assemblies? How?
- Creating new submodules with the corresponding pom files (and in there the GAV the costumer requires) inside each one of the modules which should be deployed, but each of these submodules would basically only copy the artifacts from targetA/app--, targetB/... and targetC/... This way I hope at least having a more or less clean deploy step (without using a deploy-file to deploy a WAR and a pom). The pom files would be minimal and viewed from the root-module we would still see only one module 'mod' and hide the ugliness inside this rather than having 3 modules 'modA', 'modB' and 'modC'. This way we would also decouple the devs-view and the deployments-view on the project. Devs could continue the way they are used to and integrators would take care of the 'putting things in the way the customer wants it'-part. Now here my question is: **how can I create a maven project where the 'complete build' is actually nothing more than copying a war?**

It is clear to me, that all these choices are horrible. If you know of the 'right way' to solve my problem I would really appreciate it. Otherwise I would really just like to know how to achieve the 'copying a war' part.

Comment: If you want to have 3 different artifactIds, I'd encourage to use 3 maven modules. In the end that's clear for everybody. It would be quite hard to trace back the sources if the artifactId doesn't match with that value in the pom.

Comment: What did you do until now? Use classifiers? Or version numbers?

Comment: @JFMeier Until now we were using both until now. But our whole delivery-process was different. So whatever was until now unfortunately doesn't apply anymore. (I'm adding it to the question)

Comment: Best is simply to make three different modules of it....as already mentioned....